# makeEditable doesnt work in jquery datatables

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I have used the foloowing code to display data from database in jquery datatables:

```
  $(document).ready(function() { 
    var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
     "bProcessing": true,
     "bServerSide": true,
     "sAjaxSource": "server.php" }
     ); 
     } );
```

The data is displayed without any problem.

But when I want to add/update n delete data which is displayed it doesnt work.
ex.

```
 var oTable = $('#example').dataTable.makeEditable( {
```

when I try the above line all the data dissapears. How do I add and delete. I tried exampls mentioned in datatables website but they dont work for me.

Comment: datatables already has it's own implementation for this using the jEditable plugin. http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/editable.html

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan:
Thanks for prompt reply. I have already included the plugin in my file.
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="media/js/jquery.jeditable.js" ></script>
Should I direcctly use the code that is given in the link provided by you?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan:
What I want to know is I have my above code which displays data from database. I need help in modifying the above code so as to add "Add" and delete functionality. the changes must be reflected in the database too